# Jquery dynamically added inputs to form have not POST data PHP

Tags: input, dynamically-generated

I'm adding `<input>` fields in form using jquery `html()` on click event.

`$('#container').html('<input type="text" name="ce" value="some" >');`

after submitting php POST i'm unable to see index `ce` with `print_r($_POST);`

is there any special method to add elements to dom for this ? please advise.

Comment: How about using `.append()` instead of `.html()`?

Comment: Show us the rest of your form html and make sure the new input field is inside the form element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `$('#container').html` you are not adding a new input, you are replacing all your content with this new input..

try `$('#container').append` tag

Look at this example -> https://jsfiddle.net/660a3t1g/

```
    $('#myInputs').append('<input type="text" placeholder="LastName: " name="some" >');
```

Answer (score 3):

**Solved !** Thanks for answering.  in my scenario even with `append` it didn't work. now it's done with my previous code using `html()`. Problem was wrapping the `<form>`. my table is large i'm only pointing out the problem. my structure was suppose to like:

```
<table>
<tr>
<form id="myform">
<td><input type="text" name="name" ></td>
<td>
<div id="container">
<!-- dynamically generated inside this div against it's id (which didn't work) -->
<input type="text" name="ce" >  
</div>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>
```

i simply Put the entire table into the 'form' tags

```
<form id="myform">
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="name" ></td>
<td>
<div id="container">
<input type="text" name="ce" > <!-- dynamically generated inside div (works!) -->
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

it worked perfectly with both `append()` and `html()`. hope will be helpful for someone.